# Android - Audio Clipping when recording audio (crest/peak clipping and periodic 0 bit values in between)

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I am trying to record an audio stream via a Bluetooth device. I am using Bluetooth SCO for getting Bluetooth audio and AudioRecord class to record audio.
I am recording RAW `.PCM` files with `MONO` Channel with a sampling rate of 16000

I am calculating BufferSize like this

```
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE_FACTOR = 2;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE_IN_HZ,CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT) * BUFFER_SIZE_FACTOR;
```

This is how I am getting/writing audio currently,

```
private class RecordingRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setFileNameAndPath();
        
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);
        try (final FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath)) {
            while (recordingInProgress.get()) {
                int result = recorder.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                if (result < 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Reading of audio buffer failed: " +
                            getBufferReadFailureReason(result));
                }
                outStream.write(buffer.array(), 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                buffer.clear();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Writing of recorded audio failed", e);
        }

    }
```

I did a little research and found that the clipping effect could be because of the wrong Byte order `(LITTLE_ENDIAN or BIG_ENDIAN)` or Because of poor multithreading. However in this current implementation, I am not able to understand how bytes are being ordered and saved & what can I do to fix the clipping/noise problem.

I am starting my recorder runnable like this

```
    recordingThread = new Thread(new RecordingRunnable(), "Recording Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
    recordingThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and I resolved this problem with below code.

```
    private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData, int size) {
        int shortArrsize = size;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
            bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
            bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
            sData[i] = 0;
        }
        return bytes;

    }
```

......

```
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

            int source = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION;

            mAudioRecorder = new AudioRecord(source, 48000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
            int state = mAudioRecorder.getState();
            if (state != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can not support");
                return;
            }

            mAudioRecorder.startRecording();

            while (mIsRecording) {
                int bufferReadResult = mAudioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                if (bufferReadResult < 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    byte data[] = short2byte(buffer, bufferReadResult);
                    fos.write(data, 0, bufferReadResult * 2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks a ton for this answer It fixed my clipping issue but when I plot raw data into audacity I still some periodic 0-bit values which are also hearable in audio as tick-tick background noise. But still a lot better than before.